# Google spreadsheet column value to html page

Tags: html, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I would like to make a notice page in my googlesites from the spreadsheet cell data. 
The below is sample html from the W3 CSS Taps. [W3 CSS Taps](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_tabulators)

Please help how i can put the cell values to the < P > tags.

[image: html sample]

[image: Sheet Sample]

```js
function getData(){  
  var ssID = "SHEET ID",
      ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[2],
      data = ws.getRange(1, 1,ws.getLastRow(),4).getValues();
  var lastRow = getLastRow(data);

    Logger.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

```html
  <div id="London" class="w3-container w3-border city">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p id="str1"></p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Paris</h2>
    <p id="str2"></p> 
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Tokyo</h2>
    <p id="str3"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Using your W3 schools link as a reference, did you remember to add your CDN? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">`

Comment: Yes, CDN is working and I am trying to use apps script with spreadsheet for the html values. I looked Templated HTML from the apps script however i could not find solution.

Comment: Read `google.script.run`See Html best practices in [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make a use of the [`HTMLService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) of `App Script`.

There are actual guides to make templated HTML [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates). Being more specific for your case you can actually [push variables from apps script to your templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates).

So create an *html* file in your project like so:

```html
  <div id="London" class="w3-container w3-border city">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p id="str1"><?= london ?></p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Paris</h2>
    <p id="str2"><?= paris ?></p> 
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Tokyo</h2>
    <p id="str3"><?= tokyo ?></p>
  </div>
```

And then serve this page through apps script like so:

```
function doGet() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  t.london = ss.getRange("A2").getValue();
  t.paris = ss.getRange("B2").getValue();
  t.tokyo = ss.getRange("C2").getValue();
  return t.evaluate();
}
```

Of course you can change the logic behind getting the values to your templated HTML.

---

Also another option could be to have a function to be able to get this information through JavaScript, for that option take a look at this guide for [Client-to-Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).